# Increasing the size of an array by passing it as an argument to function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun1(int a[100])
{
  a[4]=1;
}
void main()
{
   int a[2]={1,2};
   fun1(a);
   printf("%d",a[4]);   // Output 1
}
```

I know that arrays get decayed to pointer to first element when we pass it as a function argument. But how does the size of array increase in main function ?

Comment: It doesn't, it's just a case of **undefined behavior**. See [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) for an alternative result.

Comment: It does not increase. C just doesn't check the size, and you are reading/writing to memory location which belongs to who-knows-who.

Comment: The compiler only takes notice of the array length when you have another dimension, so it knows how to index it. For example `void fun1(int a[][3]);`. Having done that you can read `a[0][20]` if you like, but it will be undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ **shall be adjusted
>   to** ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any)
>   are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation....

This means that in the declaration

```
void fun1(int a[100])
{
  a[4]=1;
}
```

the function parameter is adjusted to the type `int *` and as result the function in fact has the following declaration

```
void fun1( int *a )
{
  a[4]=1;
}
```

So for example the following function declarations

```
void fun1(int a[2]);
void fun1(int a[10]);
void fun1(int a[100]);
```

declare the same one function which declaration looks like

```
void fun1(int *a);
```

On the other hand an array used in expressions as for example as a function argument is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So in this function call with the expression using the array designator

```
fun1(a);
```

the array designator `a` is converted to pointer to its first element and the argument's expression has the type `int *`.

You can imagine this call the following way

```
{
    int *temporary p = a;
    fun1( p );
}
```

So the function parameter has the type `int *` that is it is a pointer and the corresponding argument also a pointer. The function does not deal with an object of an array type. It deals with an object of pointer type.

So neither array increases its size and the original program has undefined behavior because there is an attempt to access memory beyond the original array.

You can easy check that the function deals with a pointer by outputting the size of the parameter. For example

```
void fun1(int a[100])
{
    printf( "sizeof( a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
    a[4]=1;
}
```

The output will be equal to either `4` or `8` depending on the used system. But in any case it will not be equal to `100 * sizeof( int )` as you could expect.

Answer (score 2):

You **cant** change size of automatic array runtime.

If you want to choose size of declared automatic array in runtime, you can use (since c99) [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n)
int a[n];
```

or if you really need to change size of array runtime, you have to dynamically allocate memory on heap and then [realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) size of buffer.

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
int *tmp = realloc(a, sizeof(int) * 4);
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    // Reallocation failed
}
else
{
    a = tmp;
}
```

---

As @DavidBowling remarked, its better to use dereferenced identifiers instead of types in sizeof expressions. In our case it would be

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof *a * 2);
int *tmp = realloc(a, sizeof *tmp * 4);
```

its easier & less error-prone when types of pointers change.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it is better to prefer identifiers in `sizeof` expressions over explicit types. This is less error-prone and easier to maintain when types change: `int *a = malloc(sizeof *a * 2);`, and `int *tmp = realloc(a, sizeof *tmp * 4);`.